# Why is my while going in a infinity loop? How do I fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop, do-while, negative-number

I dont know why my do while is going on infinity and not showing my output which should be how many quaters, dimes ,etc has that amount of money that the user input in the system.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the amount of money: ");
    float dinero= scan.nextFloat();
    int quaters=0;
    int dimes =0;
    int nickle =0;
    int pennys =0;
    boolean b=false;
    do{
        if(dinero>=0.25){

            dinero=(float) (dinero-0.25);
            quaters++;

        }else if(dinero<0.25 && dinero>=0.10){

            dinero=(float) (dinero-0.10);
            dimes++;

        }else if(dinero<0.10 && dinero>=0.05){

            dinero=(float) (dinero-0.05);
            nickle++;

        }else if(dinero<0.05 && dinero<0){

            dinero=(float) (dinero-0.01);
            pennys++;
        }else{
            b=true;
        }


    }while(b==false);

    System.out.println("Quater :"+quaters);
    System.out.println("Dimes :"+dimes);
    System.out.println("Nickle :"+nickle);
    System.out.println("Pennys :"+pennys);
```

Please help i know this is a dumb question but help will be much apprishiated.

Comment: My guess is that your final `&& dinero<0` should be `&& dinero > 0`. Note that using `float` for currency values is a bad idea...

Comment: Looks like b will always be false

Comment: The BigDecimal is maybe a better choice for money and currency implementations.

Comment: some tipps: 1. use while(b) {something} instead of do { something} while (b) if you can, because you can see the loop condition before entering it (better readability); 2. use while(b) and while(!b) instead of while(b==true) or while(b==false); 3. use better names than "b". It is easier to understand your code, when you know, what b should mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it it was that my last condition was wrong. Also the while was wrong

```
else if(dinero<0.05 && dinero>=0.01){

// was the the fix for the last else if         

while(dinero>0.01);
 // and here is the while
```

Comment: you answer to yourself ... lol ... you may want to accept the answer of @Aurasphere ... he gave you the right pointer some 15mn ago ...

Comment: Thank you @Pras. Also I'm glad I could help you if that's the case.

Comment: @Pras self-answering is nothing strange on SO and is even encouraged. But not when you already got a valid answer of course.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to do but here is your problem: the last else is never executed because you covered all the possible cases in the if instructions before. Because of that, b will always be false and therefore your loop will go on forever. In which condition do you exactly want to exit this loop? Think about this and then move the instruction in the last else into the corresponding if block. Also, the if before that is not correct either. You probably meant:

```
if(dinero<0.5 && dinero>=0){
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use sorted if statement, if you can. So "if (0<=dinero && dinero < 0.5)" is better because you can see directly dinero is between 0 (incl) and 0.5 (excl)

Comment: Yeah, I definitely agree with you, but in this case I preferred to keep the order used in the question just to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

change the condition of your else if statement to

```
else if(dinero<0.05 && dinero>0)
```